# How to use Starlette and pydantic together

Tags: python, pydantic, starlette

I am trying to use Pydantic to get user value in my Starlette application. How do i do so ?

```
class Post(BaseModel):
title:str
content:str

@app.route("/createposts",methods=["POST"])
async def create_posts(request):
    data = await request.json()
    print(data)
    return JSONResponse({"data":data})
```

Comment: validate your `data` with your `Post` model.

Comment: @monkut can you teach how it is done ?

Comment: `parsed_post = Post(data)`

Comment: Take a look at the documentation, the documentation for pydantic is pretty clear.  https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/#example

Comment: You should just use FastAPI, I think. It is based on both Starlette and Pydantic!

Answer (score 0):

```
 from starlette.applications import Starlette
 from starlette.responses import JSONResponse

 from pydantic import BaseModel
 from pydantic import ValidationError
 from typing import Optional
 app = Starlette()

class Post(BaseModel):
    title:str
    content:str
    rating:Optional[int]=None
 
@app.route("/createposts",methods=["POST"])
async def create_posts(request):
    data = await request.json()
        try:
            parsed_post = Post(**data)
        except ValidationError as e:
            return JSONResponse({"error":e.json()})

    return JSONResponse({"post_data":"Post Create Successfully"})
```

Thank you @monkut

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).